# How to cut a list by specific item?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to cut a list by specific items in it, for example, I have a list like this:

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
```

What I want is:

```
[["a", "b"]["c", "d", "b"] ["e", "r"]]
```

which is cut after every occurrence of `"b"`.

I wrote something like this:

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
up = []
while down is not []:
    up, down = up.append(down[:(down.index("b") + 1)]), down[(down.index("b") + 1):]
```

It throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @patrick has the answer you need. as for what's wrong, you're trying to assign `up` with `up.append(something)`. you shouldn't assign while using a list method/function. What ends up happening is that the append method modifies the object, and then the function returns a None. Combined with an assignment, you modify the list but then bind `up` name to None. Next iteration, you get the error that's showing.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I am confused. I rewrote my code like this:         
`down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
up = []
while "b" in down:
    up.append(down[:(down.index("b") + 1)])
    down = down[(down.index("b") + 1):]
up.append(down)`          @ParitoshSingh

Comment: @frankzheng43 check out my answer you may find it interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you assign the result of the `list.append()` function - which is `None` - to `up` in

> ```
> up, down = up.append(down[: (down.index("b") + 1)]), down[...snipp...] 
> #          ^^^^^^^^ returns None
> ```

`list.append` is a "in-place" operation that returns `None` so `up` is going to be `None` in the next iteration.

Keeping closest to what you got you could use

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
up = []
while 'b' in down:
    b_index = down.index('b') + 1
    up.append(down[:b_index])
    down = down[b_index:]
up.append(down)
```

but simply iterating your original and assembling the sublists in a second list is cleaner in my opinion:

```
k = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]

result = [[]]
for e in k:
    if e != "b":
        result[-1].append(e)
    else:
        result[-1].append(e)
        result.append([])

if result[-1] == []: 
    result.pop() # thx iBug's comment

print(result) # [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'b'], ['e', 'r']]
```

I think that is much clearer then what your code tries to do - your "what I want `["a", "b"]["c", "d", "b"] ["e", "r"]`" is not valid python.

---

A slightly different version of the code would be:

```
k = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
b = []
while True:
    try:
        b_idx = k.index("b")
    except: 
        b.append(k)
        break
    else:
        b,k = b+[k[:b_idx+1]],k[b_idx+1:]
print(b)
```

But you need far mor searches into your list via `.index()` and `try: except` so it has a worse performance then simply iterating the list once.

Comment: `result = result[:-1]` -> `result.pop()`

Comment: What merits the dv on a 2y old question? Suggestion what to improve?

Answer (score 1):

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
poslist = []
for pos, item in enumerate(down):
    if item == 'b':
        poslist.append(pos)
answerlist = []
for i in range(len(poslist)):
    if i == 0:
        answerlist.append(down[:poslist[i]+1])
    else:
        answerlist.append(down[poslist[i-1]+1:poslist[i]+1])
answerlist.append(down[poslist[i]+1:])
print (answerlist)
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'b'], ['e', 'r']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(down ) if x == "b"]
curr=0
master_list=[]
for item in indices:
    master_list.append(down[curr:item+1])
    print(master_list)
    curr=item+1
if curr !=len(down):
    master_list.append(down[curr:len(down)])
print(master_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [59]: k
Out[59]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'l', 'f', 'b', 's']

In [60]: indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(k) if x == "b"]  # all index of 'b'

In [61]: aa = k[:indices[0]+1] # first list

In [62]: bb = k[indices[len(indices)-1]+1:]  # last list

In [63]: for i in range(0, len(indices)-1):
    ...:     print(k[indices[i]+1:indices[i+1]+1]) # remaining list
    ...: 
['c', 'd', 'b']
['e', 'r', 'l', 'f', 'b']

In [64]: aa
Out[64]: ['a', 'b']

In [65]: bb
Out[65]: ['s']
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.append(elem)` does not return the new list, just modifies the original. That's the reason for your error.

To correct your code without changing the approach:

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]
up = []
while True:
    if 'b' in down: # make sure there is a 'b' in the list
        index = down.index("b") # get the index of the first "b"
        up.append(down[:index + 1]) # save first sublist in up
        down = down [index + 1:] # trim the sublist you already saved 
    else:
        up.append(down) # add the rest of down
        break # leave the loop 
print(up)
```

Answer (score 1):

What would a question like this be without an `itertools` answer?

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in this case, with a custom key that counts past occurrences of `'b'`:

```
from itertools import groupby

class CountKey:
    def __init__(self, what):
        self.what = what
        self.count = 0
    def __call__(self, item):
        count = self.count
        if item == self.what:
            self.count += 1
        return count

up = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(down, CountKey('b'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple one-liner to make the job:**

```
import re

d = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]

s = '(?<=b)'

print ([list(x) for x in re.split(s,"".join(d))])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'b'], ['e', 'r']]
```

The difficulty here is to keep the delimiter in the "left" sublist. The `re.split()` method can do that in association with a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a list of indices, then use a list comprehension:

```
down = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "e", "r"]

n = len(down)
idx = [index+1 for index, value in enumerate(down) if value == 'b']

res = [down[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx, idx + ([n] if idx[-1] != n else []))]

# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'b'], ['e', 'r']]
```

The ternary statement `[n] if idx[-1] != n else []` is used to avoid an empty final list if the last value in `down` is `'b'`. This is a two-pass solution, but uses list slicing as opposed to explicitly appending items one at a time.